# Is it possible to use a TP-Link Archer T8E wireless card on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers

I built a computer recently and did not do my research for this card. I'm also completely new to Linux (Planning to duel boot later but for now I'm trying to learn Ubuntu) and I'm having a hard time finding good tutorials to follow to learn the basics/

All that to say: I don't know what I'm doing! I need some serious guidance. Any help/pointers/advice and learning materials greatly appreciated.

I have access to ethernet (Though not at the moment) and a secondary computer, but no optical drives.

Thank you. I've only just dipped my toes into the water here but I can already tell this is a really passionate community, I'm excited. Have a cool day.

ran `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and got:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4630 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0]
(rev 03)
       Subsystem Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0619]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional details about your wireless device from the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu!

Comment: K, thank you! Got some numbers and words and some combinations of numbers/letters. I know I need a driver, not sure how this info gets me there... Yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the installation USB, insert it and and drill down to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag bcmwl-kernel-source to your desktop. Do the same with pool > main > d > dkms and drag dkms to you desktop. Then install:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: It worked! amazing. Thank you. The command `sudo modprobe w1` didn't do anything, but Wifi is ON.

Comment: It is `wl` not w1. That is, lower-case for WL. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 1):

It will work with proprietary Broadcom driver. Make sure your PC is connected to LAN and then go to Additional driver and you will see the Broadcom listed there, enable it and reboot.

Comment: I've just bought the T9E and it worked with your solution. Thanks!