# TP-Link Archer T9E in Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, server

I have my NAS running *Ubuntu Server 14.04*, now I need to add a PCIe AC wireless card and I want to use this one, **Archer T9E**:

http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-11_Archer-T9E.html

but in that site there's only windows drivers,

so, is this card compatible with *Ubuntu Server 14.04*? has anybody try this combination before? or what card should I buy?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a TP-Link Archer T8E wireless card on Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689057/is-it-possible-to-use-a-tp-link-archer-t8e-wireless-card-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @Pilot6 nothing, bcos I don't have the card yet, I don't want to buy a card that doesn't work:
seele@heimdall:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
seele@heimdall:~$

Comment: You need to find out what chip is inside.

Comment: @Amias This is another adapter.

Comment: @Amias maybe, but t9e is ac1900 and t8e is ac1750

Comment: It is much more important which chip is inside, not the speed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping recommendations and hardware compatibility (theoretical) is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adapter is based on BCM4360 chip. It is supported by the proprietary Broadcom driver (`wl`).

[Source](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T9E)

But Tp-Link is known for changing the hardware in their products without changing the brand name, just a revision. They may release a completely new product with the same name.